# Same origin policy exceptions: window.location

Tags: javascript, security, same-origin-policy

According to my notes:
"A document can always update the location of another document if they have some relationship. Typical relationships include one document opened by the other via the window.open DOM API".
I tried to test it by doing the following:

1. Opened firefox and pointed it to https://www.google.com.
2. On that tab, I opened the console tab and typed: `window.open("https://www.nzpost.co.nz"`.
3. I then switched tabs to the google tab and typed the following: `window.opener.location="https://www.bing.com"`.

This produced the following error:
`Uncaught TypeError: window.opener is null <anonymous> debugger eval code:1`

To my understanding, the nzpost tab should be able to access the location of the google tab. Am I wrong in my understanding of SOP or is this a browser specific security feature. I've also tested on edge with the same result.